# how to delete lines containing a string AND also NOT containing some other string?

Tags: regex

I need some regular expression help.

Using the Firefox firebug extension, "css-usage", I was able to export a new css file where the utility prepended "UNUSED" to every class that was not referenced in the page.

I would like to now remove every style that contains the UNUSED styles, however there are some complexities with that.  Namely, some tags are comma separated with other tags/selectors which may still be used so I don't want to delete any lines that have a comma in it.  And secondly some styles are specified in a long multi-line block in curly braces, so I don't want to delete any lines that do not have a closing curly brace '}'.

I'm using a mac so any solution with SED or AWk or vi is acceptable.  I would like to delete all lines in a css file that starts with "UNUSED" and contains no commas and must have a closing '}' curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

To test if a string contains a character without capturing that character or moving the pointer forward, use a lookahead.

```
(?=.*[,])
```

Or, to make sure the string does not contain that character, use a negative lookahead.

```
(?!.*[,])
```

If you want to make sure that a string does not contain a character but does contain other characters, you can combine negative and positive lookaheads.

```
(?!.*[,])(?=.*[}])(?=.*UNUSED)
```

Finally, to actually select the entire string where this match occurs, use .* after the lookaheads.

```
^(?!.*[,])(?=.*[}])(?=.*UNUSED).*$
```

I am mostly familiar with .NET, but I believe many regex engines have options that allow you to specify whether `^` and `$` will match the beginning/ending of the entire input string or the beginning/ending of a line. You'd want the second option.

Finally, you could use a regex replace to replace lines that match the given expression with an empty string (thus "deleting" those lines).

Answer (score 0):

To match `UNUSED` without commas and ensure that it ends with `}`:

```
UNUSED [^,]*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
^UNUSED[^,]*}[^,]*$
```

with multi-line modifier.